# Save output to a text file from Mac terminal

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

How could I enter a command, say, system_profiler, and have the output save somewhere on my computer?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply with [output redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
system_profiler > file.txt
```

Basically, this will take the output of `system_profiler` and save it to the file `file.txt`. There are technically two different output "streams", standard output, and standard error. They are treated separately, and if you use the simple redirection method above, you will only redirect standard output to the file. If you want to redirect *both* standard output and standard error, you could do this:

```
system_profiler &> file.txt
```

The `&` tells the shell to redirect the standard output and standard error to the file.

If you want to *just* output standard error, you can do this:

```
system_profiler 2> file.txt
```

The `2` lets the shell know that it needs to only redirect standard error.

Using the `>` will overwrite the file if it's already there. If you want to append it to a file without erasing the old one, you can use `>>`, like so:

```
system_profiler >> file.txt
```

You can of course use the `&` and `2` for sending both standard out and standard error, and just standard error with the `>>` operator.

Comment: &>> doesn't seem to work in Mac Bash version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11). I when I try it, it says `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token >`. Everything else works.

Answer (score 4):

Redirection.

```
awesomo > somefile.txt
```